# Is there any built-in MSMOTE library?

Tags: unbalanced-classes

I am trying to deal with data imbalance within a small dataset. Just found an article talking about SMOTE and MSMOTE [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/#comment-126470)

It seems that MSMOTE can overcome the shortages of SMOTE, so I really want to try it. MSMOTE paper is published in 2009, however I could not find any library related to MSMOTE in R or python.

Do you know whether there is any built-in **MSMOTE** I could try? I'm fine with whatever programming language...

Comment: There is a python implementation [here](https://github.com/rpmcruz/machine-learning/blob/master/utilities/preprocessing/smote.py). Disclaimer: I haven't personally verified the validity. However, I am on the lookout for an R implementation.